# Edge extension crashes the whole browser on API call after latest update (launchWebAuthFlow)

Tags: javascript, crash, microsoft-edge, browser-extension

**EDIT: THIS HAS JUST BEEN FIXED IN THE 98.0.1108.43 UPDATE!**
**EDIT2: NEVERMIND! THE LOGIN POPUP WINDOW NOW SHOWS, BUT THE MOMENT YOU TRY TO SIGN IN IT STILL CRASHES!**
**EDIT3: FINALLY FIXED :)**

I'm creating a browser extension for my work.

The function launchWebAuthFlow has worked wonderfully since I started this project, but then Edge decided to update (to 96.0.1054.43, and now again to 96.0.1054.53, and now again to 96.0.1054.57, and now again to 96.0.1054.62, now again to 97.0.1072.55, and now again to 97.0.1072.62 after MS sent me an email saying they fixed it, and now again to 97.0.1072.69, and now again to 97.0.1072.76) and now the whole browser instantly crashes when the function launchWebAuthFlow is called. I have tried downgrading Edge, but I haven't found any download links to previous versions.

My `authUrl` looks like this (and has worked this far before the updates!):
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize`
I've stripped out the arguments for privacy.

This code alone doesn't crash, but also doesn't show any window:

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
  {
    interactive: true,
    url: authUrl
  }
);
```

This code crashes (!) and it should show a window (and this is the code I've been using which has worked for a long time until the update):

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
  {
    interactive: true,
    url: authUrl
  },
  (response) =>
  {
    console.log("This never prints, because the browser crashes!");
  }
);
```

I found this: [Chrome Extension crashes the Microsoft Edge browser while calling launchWebAuthFlow API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70187797/chrome-extension-crashes-the-microsoft-edge-browser-while-calling-launchwebauthf)

The accepted answer for that question says this is a workaround:

```
return await global.chrome.windows.create({
    focused: true,
    height : 800,
    width: 800,
    url: authURL
})
```

But it doesn't work for me. `chrome.windows.create` creates and shows a window but returns `undefined`, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: What is the `url` parameter? Fully-qualified URLs must include a scheme, e.g., `http://www.google.com`, not 'www.google.com'. Non-fully-qualified URLs are considered relative within the extension. You can also refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-rollback) to try rolling back the Edge version, which may be useful to you. In addition, I suggest that you send feedback on the problem to the relevant team, just press `Shift+Alt+I` to edit the content and send it.

Comment: @XudongPeng The `url` is fully-qualified: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize`. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the question. I just got another update in Edge, `96.0.1054.53`, this one also crashes.

Comment: Well, if this is the case, I think you have to send feedback to relvant team. I aslo hope this problem will be resolved as soon as possible.

Comment: @XudongPeng Oh I actually sent feedback a few days before I posted here. Completely forgot to tell you! haha. Do you think you can help me figure out why the "workaround" doesn't work for me? (returning undefined)

Comment: Edge updated to `96.0.1054.57` and it's still crashing.

Comment: Edge updated to `96.0.1054.62` and it's still crashing (I can't modify comments). I use the feedback system after every update and link to this post, so I'm sure the correct team knows about it by now.